# Nginx ignores root and alias directives

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve a React app build in nginx in /opt/hdr/static/hdr. React homepage and Router are pointing /static/hdr as React documentation says.

The .conf file I'm using is the next one:

```
server {
 listen   80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;

 server_name  _;

 index index.html;

 location /static/hdr/ {
   alias /opt/hdr/static/hdr/;
   index index.html;
   expires 1d;
   add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

}
```

But I'm getting a 404 error when I access mywebpage.com/static/hdr. I've tried several combinations:

1. alias /opt/hdr/static/hdr
2. root /opt/hdr
3. root /opt/hdr/static/hdr

Nothing works. The thing is, looking in the error logs of nginx I've realized that it is searching in /etc/nginx/html/static/hdr instead of /opt/hdr/static/hdr. If I put the site there everything works perfectly.

Executing nginx -V gives me that --prefix is set to /etc/nginx. This could be the reason why nginx searches in /etc/nginx but I have no idea where /html is coming from. Neither why root and alias are not overwriting it.

Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the line in the error logs?

Comment: *774 "/etc/nginx/html/static/hdr/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the complete error message. I am particularly interested in the `server:` tag and the `request:` tag.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Finally the problem was a "hidden" second configuration file that was overwriting the rules in this one.